# How to get back .svn directory if it's deleted by accident

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a server where /var/www/..... have a lot of project folder which is a working copy of many different project.

```
e.g:
/var/www/project1
/var/www/project2
/var/www/project3
```

Recently someone called a remove command recursively for all folder *.svn. Which cause all the project folder is not connected to svn anymore. I can't use 'svn stat' on any of the folder anymore.

How can I revert back or how can I get back the .svn folder that get removed accidentally. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Why don't you just get a fresh working copy from the server?

Comment: you should perhaps move what's there now in case you have some unsaved edits..

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to:

1. Create a new empty directory
2. Checkout your project from svn repository into this new directory
3. Copy your modified files to this new directory (if any)
4. Commit changes (if any)